# How do I track contacts and see their visits upon registering to my site?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, tracking

This is the method I have to register a Contact and their facets to the xDb (I have also registered some of my personal facets). However upon registering, my known contacts visits and visit duration does not show up.

[image]

I've tried adding this line according to the documentation provided by sitecore @ https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-platform/tracking-contacts.html but I'm getting this error.

[image]

How do I keep track of known contact visits upon registration with my AddContact Method?

```
public ActionResult AddContact(string email, string UEN, string phoneNumber)
        {
            using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var number = new Random();
                    var number2 = number.Next();
                    string emailAddress = number2 + "myrtle@test.test";


                    IDefinition ev = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[ABCD.iD];

                    if (ev != null)
                    {
                        var registerId = new Guid("8FFB183B-DA1A-4C74-8F3A-9729E9FCFF6A"); // Fake newsletter ID
                        var pageData = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData(ev.Alias, ev.Id);

                        pageData.Data = registerId.ToString();

                        Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(pageData);
                    }

                    Contact contact = new Contact(new ContactIdentifier("WebVisit", UEN , ContactIdentifierType.Known));

                    UENInfo uenInfo = new UENInfo()
                    {
                        UEN = UEN                    
                    };

                    client.SetFacet(contact, uenInfo);

                    // Facet with a reference object, key is specified
                    PersonalInformation personalInfoFacet = new PersonalInformation()
                    {
                        FirstName = "User" + number.Next(),
                        LastName = "McSitecore"
                    };

                    FacetReference reference = new FacetReference(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey);

                    client.SetFacet(reference, personalInfoFacet);

                    
                    // Facet without a reference, using default key
                    EmailAddressList emails = new EmailAddressList(new EmailAddress(email , true), "Home");

                    client.SetFacet(contact, emails);

                    // Facet without a reference, key is specified

                    AddressList addresses = new AddressList(new Address() { AddressLine1 = "Cool Street 12", City = "Sitecore City", PostalCode = "ABC 123" }, "Home");

                    client.SetFacet(contact, AddressList.DefaultFacetKey, addresses);


                    client.AddContact(contact); // Extension found in Sitecore.XConnect.Operations

                    // Submits the batch, which contains two operations
                    client.Submit();

                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    // Manage exception
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: May I know the Sitecore version you're using ?

Comment: You can try checking the logs from the XConnect site folder to see if there is any exception / error messages there.

Comment: Have you done an upgrade to get to this point? IdentifyAs() is still the method to identify users in Sitecore. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Please check the details at https://github.com/AmitKumar-AK/CT.SC/blob/master/src/Feature/Accounts/code/Controllers/AccountsController.cs and it may be helpful to implement required use case.